# Es seguro guardar un token jwt en LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, jwt

Tengo una react-app y almaceno el token jwt en localStorage. He estado investigando y algunos recomiendan usar sesiones. Mi duda es que riesgos corro.

Cualquiera podría usar el token y generar llamadas a mis Apis.

Comment: Hola Anderson, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre nosotros). Esta es una pregunta bastante interesante, ¿cómo lo estás haciendo ahora? ¿Podrías poner referencias a dónde dicen de usar sesiones? Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando logueo al usuario obtengo su token y lo guardo en LocalStorage y con ese comienzo a generar mis llamadas a api pero de mi punto de vista lo veo muy inseguro. Adjunto el articulo que lei. https://alexanderpaterson.com/posts/protecting-react-applications-against-csrf-with-express-sessions

Answer (score 8):

> Cualquiera podría usar el token y generar llamadas a mis Apis

Cualquiera que **tenga acceso al PC del cliente, a su sesión y a su navegador**. Llegado a este punto es responsabilidad del usuario proteger su computadora y sus cuentas, no del desarrollador. Si permite al navegador que guarde su usuario y contraseña (es algo muy habitual), cualquiera que pueda leer el localStorage podría también simplemente entrar al navegador y abrir una nueva sesión.

En conclusión: no hay problema por usar el localStorage, siempre y cuando borres el token cuando el usuario decida cerrar la sesión (podrías usar `sessionStorage`, pero el concepto de sesión del navegador puede ser un poco restrictivo si quieres que el token dure horas o incluso días).
Lo que sí te aconsejo es mandar el token como un header, no como cookie, para evitar ataques CSRF.

Puedes encontrar más información en esta respuesta de [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357182/csrf-token-necessary-when-using-stateless-sessionless-authentication)

Comment: Hola Pablo, Claro el token lo envió por header. Gracias por aclararme este punto.Saludos

Comment: @Anderson creo que ha resolvido su questión. Podrías ponder la flag `[resolvido]` al título?

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues dos cosas: es **resuelto** y no debe hacer eso, sino marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Mmm entendi, gracias!