# Cambio de token en localstorage, permite obtener información de otro usuario react js

Tags: reactjs, api, tokens, frontend

Estoy consumiendo una API en react js. Obtengo la información del usuario (username, email, permisos, etc.) a partir de su token, que almaceno en localstorage. Sin embargo, al reemplazarlo por otro token válido de otro usuario me obtiene los datos de este último. Creo que es un grave problema de seguridad. ¿Existe alguna manera de solventarlo?

Por ahora se me ocurre comparar el valor de localstorage con un state con contenga el token. Considero que no es lo mejor pues tendrá que ser necesaria en cada petición al backend. Otra solución podría ser refrescar el token.

Este problema queda expuesto por ejemplo cuando el usuario desea editar su perfil.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Como obtuviste ese otro token válido?

Comment: Teniendo acceso a otra sesión. Pero como se indica [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149161/es-seguro-guardar-un-token-jwt-en-localstorage?rq=1) puede ser responsabilidad del usuario no del dev